# Can the js controllers in the org/alfresco/modules be extended or overridden in Alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to extend the `create-event.js` controller in the webscript in the path `org/alfresco/module/`. I created a function which is meant to add additional data in the model object yet I get an error regarding the original objects that are supposed to be instantiated in the model object. This leads me to the conclusion that the controller was over-ridden rather than extended.

Is it possible to extend webscripts in this path?

The code:

```
var connector = remote.connect("alfresco");
var themes1url = "/event-constraints/group";
var list1 = connector.get(themes1url);

var themesList1 = eval('(' + list1.response + ')');

if (themesList1 !== null || themesList1 !== undefined)
    model.themesList1 = themesList1.constraintValues;
```

Comment: Please include the changed code in your question.

Comment: which version are we talking about?

Comment: @Miki share version 4.2.c